# Javascript router for React with hooks

Tags: javascript, react.js

So I am learning hooks and context, and I wanted to make a simple router. I wanted a simple API where you can just pass in routes. `initialRoute` should be optional, and it should pick it up from the pathname, otherwise it defaults to the first route.

I want to expand it to be able to work when server side rendering, since it heavily relys on window location pathname. So I am looking for critic on my typings, my hook usage, how to prepare for server side rendering. Also just looking for any feedback if this is a good way to do a router :)

Below I have linked to a repo where I use this code, and a gist with a `usage.tsx` file to see how I am using it.

```js
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import UrlPattern from 'url-pattern'
import { IRoute, IRouterContext, IRoutes, IState } from './types'

const getRoute = (routeName: string) => (i: { name: string }) =>
    i.name === routeName

const RouterContext = createContext<IRouterContext>(null!)

const RouterProvider = (props: {
    children: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element
    routes: IRoutes
    initialRoute?: string
}) => {
    if (props.routes.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('You must provide routes')
    }

    const [currentRoute, setCurrentRoute] = useState<IRoute>(() => {
        const initialRoute = props.initialRoute
            ? props.routes.find(getRoute(props.initialRoute))
            : props.routes.find(({ path }) =>  // eslint-disable-line
                new UrlPattern(path).match(window.location.pathname), // eslint-disable-line
            ) // eslint-disable-line

        return initialRoute || props.routes[0]
    })

    const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState<IState>(() =>
        new UrlPattern(currentRoute.path).match(window.location.pathname),
    )

    const goTo = useMemo(
        () => (toRouteName: string, toState: IState = {}) => {
            const toRoute: IRoute | undefined = props.routes.find(
                getRoute(toRouteName),
            )

            if (!toRoute) {
                throw new Error(`Route ${toRouteName} does not exist`)
            }

            setCurrentRoute(toRoute)
            setCurrentState(toState)
        },
        [currentRoute.name],
    )

    useEffect(() => {
        const pattern = new UrlPattern(currentRoute.path)
        const path = pattern.stringify(currentState)

        if (path !== window.location.pathname) {
            window.history.pushState(null, '', path)
        }
    }, [currentRoute.path, currentState])

    return (
        <RouterContext.Provider
            value={{ goTo, state: currentState, currentRoute }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </RouterContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { RouterContext, RouterProvider }
```

Links:

[gist](https://gist.github.com/bitttttten/67c16fd35061e8fd329301911df6846b)

[github repo](https://github.com/bitttttten/simmer/blob/fdbc7f11cdd7724dae88572b247eaabba360afa2/src/router/index.tsx)